# Wix's util:CloseApplication extension doesn't seem to work

Tags: wix, close-application

I'm trying to close a process before uninstallation using Wix. I've confirmed that it works as long as there's a visible window, but if there isn't a visible window (which is the case most of the time with this app since it's a system tray app), the uninstaller just hangs, and eventually continues with the uninstallation, leaving the process running.

According to [this forum post](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_name=E66649032AD92B42901BF5835C76A27F51CC%40harwood.x2systems.com), it seems like Wix has had trouble closing minimized apps in the past, so I wonder if this is related?

Any suggestions as to what else I can do to make sure the process gets shut down? Is there any way I can try and capture the message in my app using the Win32 api maybe?

Here's the CloseApplication declaration:

```
<util:CloseApplication Id="CloseApp" CloseMessage="yes" Target="App.exe" RebootPrompt="yes" />
```

And here's the custom action:

```
<Custom Before="InstallInitialize" Action="WixCloseApplications">REMOVE = "ALL"</Custom>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are scheduling the `WixCloseApplications` custom action before the installation transaction. The way the custom action works, is it scheduled a deferred action that actually closes the applications. It can't do that work unless it happens during the transaction (`After="InstallInitialize"`).

The fix is probably pretty easy. Remove the `Custom/@Action="WixCloseApplications"` element.

Answer (score 3):

At first, don't forget to reference **WixUtilExtension.dll** assembly.
Also check if **Wix** element contains definition of **UtilExtension** namespace:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
```

I've noticed that you should change your custom action to be executed before InstallInitialize.

```
<Custom Before="InstallInitialize" Action="WixCloseApplications">REMOVE = "ALL"</Custom>
```

If you apply those changes and CloseApplications extension doesn't work, try logging installation process using

```
msiexec /i MyApplication.msi /l*v MyLogFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem.
Changing the Before attribute to "InstallValidate" worked for me.

```
<Custom Before="InstallValidate" Action="WixCloseApplications"/>
```